# Labeling data clusters by nearest metropolitan area using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, hot-spot

When using ArcGIS [Optimized Hotspot Analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005p00000058000000), I get two outputs. A raster like the image below, and the point incident data categorized by the various confidence thresholds for hot/cold spots.

[image]

Let's say the lower left red hotspot represents Denver, Colorado.

How can I have ArcGIS automatically label these points of interest without manually reviewing each city on the map across the country?

Using the point data, would I utilize boundary areas for major cities of interest to label points based on which region they are in?

I could also use a proximity analysis if the metropolitan areas are expressed as points.

Using the raster data, how would I identify concentrated areas?

Is there a method to convert the raster to clusters and then repeat the process above?